# Can you change the root attribute of a derived Oracle object type?

Tags: oracle, inheritance, derived-types, object-relational-model

I have 2 user-defined Oracle object types:

- Parent Type A, and
- Child Type B

//------------------------------------------------------- >>

Parent Type A has attributes as follows:
|Parent Type A |
| ------|
|* id Number |
|* data String |
|* name String |

//------------------------------------------------------- >>

I would like to change the "data" attributes so that it can be other types, besides String, in the case that I want to derive other Child types.

Per Oracle doc (on "Inheritance in SQL Object Types"):

"A subtype cannot drop or change the type of an
attribute it inherited from its parent; it can only add new attributes."

My initial attempt is to see how setting the "data" attribute (of root Parent Type A) as the base type of SYS.ANYDATA (or SYS.ANYTYPE), may work. My hopes are that I can have derived type(s) assign a string, or even a RowType datatype, into "data", by setting it up initially as a generic type.

---

###[References]###
**Oracle Database Object-Relational Developer's Guide, 19c**, via
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/object-relational-developers-guide.pdf

Comment: The documentation you quoted tells you that you can't. So what are you really asking? If the documentation is wrong and they forgot to mention a way it is possible? Why that restriction exists? Something else?

Comment: hi @AlexPoole. Thank you for the prompt response :-). How I constructed the question seems confusing. To be more specific, in a real object oriented language like C#, we know we can use generics, and then the derived types can be any type that is similar enough (ie. Int vs long). I was hoping I can use a generic-esque type (like SYS.ANYDATA) for the parent attribute, and I would be allowed to use nearly anytype for the child attribute, whether it be built-in or custom object type.

Comment: If the parent object has an `ANYDATA` attribute then the child object will also have that `ANYDATA` attribute. You cannot change the data type on the child. Just because you may be able to convert multiple types to be represented as `ANYDATA` does not mean that there is an inconsistency in the documentation. However, I feel that you are probably taking the wrong approach and are trying to force a generic solution onto a problem that almost certainly should not be solved like that (and you are explaining the XY-problem you are fixated on and not the actual problem you are solving).